# Rails: include nested through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Store model, which has an id and other fields.
I have a Product model which has an id and other field
To join them I use Amount model. Here are the models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :amounts
    has_many :stores, through: :amounts
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :amounts
    has_many :products  , through: :amounts
end

class Amount < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Amount has in_stock property. I want my json to look like this:

```
{stores: [
    {"id": 1,
     "name": "New Store",
     "products": ["id": 1, "name": "Toothbrush", "in_stock": 4000]}
]}
```

I tried render json: {stores: stores}.to_json(include: :products), I also tried a nested include but it didn't work as well, it showed output for all amounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments on my original answer (which shows in stock comes from the `Amount` model) you can include amounts in the includes relation which would be a cleaner solution and more performant...

```
output = Store.all.includes(amounts: :product).map do |store|

  { id: store.id, name: store.name,
    products: store.amounts.map do |amount|
     { id: amount.product.id, name: amount.product.name, in_stock: amount._in_stock }
    end
  }

end.to_json
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output = Store.all.includes(:products).map do |store|

  { id: store.id, name: store.name,
    products: store.products.map do |product|
     { id: product.id, name: product.name, in_stock: product.in_stock }
    end
  }

end.to_json
```

This builds an array of store hashes, each store hash has an array of products, and the hash is converted to json.

Comment: there's no method in_stock for product

Comment: This works, but 
                                       { id: product.id, name: product.name, in_stock: 
                                       store.amounts
                                       .where(:product_id => product.id)
                                       .first
                                       ._in_stock }
                                      end
                                    }
                                `